# Finding the index of a value within an Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to find the index of the smallest number of the array. My code is below and for some reason the index keeps printing the value of 9.

```
public static void main (String args [])
{
    int [] numbers = new int [10];

    //10 data inputs from user

    int smNum = numbers[0];
    int index = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < smNum)
            smNum = numbers[i];
            index = i;
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe smallest number in the array is: "+smNum+"\nThe index of this number is: "+ index); 

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tabs don't matter, curly braces do. Use them `{}`.

Comment: Java isn't Python. Add a brace to your `if (numbers[i] < smNum) {` and end it after `index = i;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what I meant.

An `if` block without curly braces only evaluates the single following expression. In other words

```
if (numbers[i] < smNum)
    smNum = numbers[i];
    index = i;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (numbers[i] < smNum) {
    smNum = numbers[i];
}
index = i;
```

where it is clear that `index = i;` will always be evaluated.

If you want multiple statements executed in an `if` block, you have to wrap those statements in curly braces.

```
if (numbers[i] < smNum) {
    smNum = numbers[i];
    index = i;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot the damn curly braces...Thanks for clearing that up and the help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding curly braces to the if block

```
int smNum = numbers[0];
int index = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] < smNum){
        smNum = numbers[i];
        index = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("\nThe smallest number in the array is: "+smNum+"\nThe index of this number is: "+ index);
```

should solve the problem. If a block, like an if clause has more than one line, you need to enclose them in curly braces. If it is only one line, no need for braces.